# RStudio and Git Yosemite

Tags: r, git, rstudio, osx-yosemite

I seem to have a path problem, perhaps of my own making.

I have Yosemite installed (fresh install) and have installed Git, BUT did not use the Xcode install. 
I installed Git directly from their website. 
I have altered the path  (this is for bash) so Git can be found from the Terminal.

I have tested Git from the Terminal and it is working.

From RStudio Preferences/ Git/SVN 
I have set the path in RStudio to the executable. (using the workaround of: 
[command] + [Shift] +[.] to see the hidden files.) 
which is set to /usr/local/git/bin/git

However when I attempt to set up a project in RStudio with Git I get the following message:

> Git was not detected on the system path.
>   To create Projects from Git repositories you should install Git and then restart 
>   RStudio.
>   Note that if Git is installed and not in the path, then you can specify its location
>   using the Preferences dialog

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of RStudio / R are you running? There is a Yosemite bug that involves environment variables and GUI applications, and RStudio and R both recently worked around this (R in 3.1.2, RStudio in the latest release [here](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/)).

Comment: Hi Version 0.98.1091 – © 2009-2014 RStudio, Inc.
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko)  R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"